# Access Nz() function doesn't work in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, function, null

I have lots of orders in tblOrders and a few deliveries in tblDeliveries.

```
SELECT tblOrders.SkuBestelId, Sum(tblDeliveries.delivered) AS TotalDelivered
FROM tblOrders
INNER JOIN tblDeliveries ON tblOrders.SkuBestelId = tblDeliveries.SkuBestelId
GROUP BY tblOrders .SkuBestelId;
```

Of course, this gives me lots of "TotalDelivered" fields with NULL values.
Since Access will return a NULL value if I use those in any kind of sum, I need to get a zero. I thought to create a field like this:

`GrandTotal: Nz([TotalDelivered], 0)`

but it didn't work: improper syntax error.

I also tried putting the Sum() function directly in the Nz() function, but that didn't do it, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Firstly, if you were to use the query as specified above, this would not return null values, as you are using an **INNER JOIN**, unless the actual delivered field contains null values.*

So, lets say you meant to use **LEFT JOIN** you could try

```
SELECT tblOrders.SkuBestelId, Sum(NZ([delivered],0)) AS TotalDelivered
FROM tblOrders LEFT JOIN 
tblDeliveries ON tblOrders.SkuBestelId = tblDeliveries.SkuBestelId
GROUP BY tblOrders.SkuBestelId;
```

Comment: Ofcourse! Put the Nz() in the Sum() and not the Sum() in the Nz().
It was indeed meant to be a LEFT JOIN. Sorry for that.